# What word is better to use here (word/talk/speech)?

Tags: word-meaning, word-request, word-in-context

It's a conversation between 3 people and I have doubts what to use for the bold part in text.

> A was telling what he was interested in and giving us some information
>
> B was trying to stop him cause it wasn't so interesting for him.
>
> but C said that "don't stop him **I like his talk**"

I wonder if it's possible to use talk in this situation?

What is the best word "word/speech/ talk or there's a better word?

Comment: You could say, "**I like what he's saying**"

Answer (score 3):

Most people would word it differently.  For example:

> Don't stop him, I want to hear this.
>
> Hold on, this is interesting.
>
> Wait a minute, I'm enjoying this discussion.
>
> Just a moment, I like his explanation.
>
> I'm enjoying his explanation.
>
> I want to hear what he's got to say.

"I like his talk" doesn't work well here.  Usually a person's "talk" refers to a relatively formal presentation they're giving.  It's also possible for people to share a talk or discussion, but then you wouldn't say "his talk".  You could say "I like the talk we're having".  Even if in practice it was a one-sided discourse, it would sound a bit odd to refer to "his talk".

"I like his conversation" might work, but is a bit too formal and would refer more to his conversations in general than to the particular instance.

"I like his speech" could mean that he was addressing a conference or a rally and you were enjoying what he was saying.  In the context of a conversation, though, "I like his speech" would sound very odd indeed, as though you were praising his particular way of pronouncing or enunciating words rather than what he was actually saying.

"I like his word" would mean that you liked one particular word that he kept on using.

Comment: "I like his speaking" would be grammatically correct (although slightly awkward), but it wouldn't really convey your intended meaning.

Comment: The only way I can picture "I like his speaking" working would be if someone had tried to shut your friend up by saying something rude like "can we stop him speaking now?" or "I've had enough of him speaking", with the word "speak" or "speaking" included.  You might then respond "But I like him speaking!".  ("I like him speaking" is the more natural way to express "I like his speaking".)

Comment: I agree with this answer for the most part, but I think you've left out one context where "I like his talk" would work just fine: I can more easily imagine, say, one the gangster characters in _Pulp Fiction_ uttering something like, "Wait; I like his talk," than, "Hold on, I am enjoying this explanation." In other words, "I like his talk" is indeed rather slangy and edgy and unusual, but, in the right context, it could work.